# Hiding Code For Specific Browser

Tags: css

If I have a simple piece of code for example

`<div> Test Div </div>`

I was wondering how (using CSS) I could make this Div appear only for users of a certain browser.

For example, what if I want to build a "Chrome only feature", like an image or a div? How do I specify not to show up in Firefox and IE?

Comment: Can you expand on exactly why you want to do this? Depending on your answer, there could be a better way to solve your problem.

Comment: I'm doing it for all the wrong reasons, I have a garbage site I'm working on. So I used a hacked fix to make something sit where I want it to and it works in every browser except Firefox so I want to just remove the image in FF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm doing it for all the wrong
>   reasons, I have a garbage site I'm
>   working on. So I used a hacked fix to
>   make something sit where I want it to
>   and it works in every browser except
>   Firefox **so I want to just remove the
>   image in FF.**

To hide an image in only Firefox, use:

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    #myImg {
        display: none
    }
}
```

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/@-moz-document

That's cleaner (and more reliable) than using JavaScript, at least for your use case.

I do think that you must be *doing it wrong* if the solution is to hide an image in only Firefox.

Comment: Ahh I was really close I just didn't have the code quite right. Thank you this is a perfect solution to my sloppy hack fix (Trust me I would prefer to do things properly but sometimes you get an ancient site and working is more important than working right.)

Answer (score 1):

There is no complete and portable solution for this. You can use server side checking and using different CSS files for different types of browsers, you can use [Conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) for Internet Explorer or you can use browser specific features or hacks.

Answer (score 0):

Set the div to display:hidden in CSS. Then setup a JavaScript function to run which detects the browser and adds that to the document.body.className attribute.

Then back in your CSS file, target it via CSS where:

body.chrome div.hidden {
      display:block!important;
   }